# Golang executed command with Run() is not returning

Tags: go, pipe

I am attempting to create a music streaming service using youtube-dl and ffmpeg. When a user sends a POST request with a video URL, my handler code works as shown below:

```golang
 router.POST("/submit", func(c *gin.Context) {
        body := Body{}
        if err := c.BindJSON(&body); err != nil {
            c.AbortWithError(http.StatusBadRequest, err)
            return
        }
        w := c.Writer
        header := w.Header()
        header.Set("Content-Type", "audio/mp3")
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
        fetchMusic(c, body.Data)
    })
func fetchMusic(c *gin.Context, data string) {

    r, w := io.Pipe()
    defer r.Close()

    ydl := exec.Command("youtube-dl", data, "-o-")
    ffmpeg := exec.Command("ffmpeg", "-i", "/dev/stdin", "-vn", "-f", "mp3", "-")

    ydl.Stdout = w
    ydl.Stderr = os.Stderr

    ffmpeg.Stdin = r
    ffmpeg.Stdout = c.Writer
    ffmpeg.Stderr = os.Stderr
    fmt.Println("Starting-----------------------")
    go func() {
        if err := ydl.Run(); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }()
    
    if err := ffmpeg.Run(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    
    fmt.Println("Done-----------------------")
}
```

I created a pipe with ffmpeg and youtube-dl. In the testing stage, I sent a POST request, but the request is not completing. If I look at the logs, I couldn't see "Done----------------". The process seems to be stuck, I think. Do you have any idea? Is my usage true?

Comment: ffmpeg will probably run until stdin is closed, but you’re not closing stdin until after ffmpeg is run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very close — we need to close the the `*io.PipeWriter` as well.

Otherwise `ffmpeg` thinks more data could come through. This will show up to the program as an `EOF`.

Here is a runnable example that I threw together, using `echo` and `cat` instead. You should be able to reproduce the issue by commenting out the new `defer w.Close()`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    r, w := io.Pipe()
    defer r.Close()

    echo := exec.Command("echo", "hello")
    cat := exec.Command("cat")

    echo.Stdout = w
    echo.Stderr = os.Stderr

    cat.Stdin = r
    cat.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cat.Stderr = os.Stderr
    fmt.Println("Starting-----------------------")
    go func() {
        // -- I added this --
        defer w.Close()
        if err := echo.Run(); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }()

    if err := cat.Run(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Done-----------------------")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As noted in a [comment by jimb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77594967/golang-executed-command-with-run-is-not-returning#comment136795549_77594967) and an [answer by coxley](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77595011/5728991), ffmpeg does not exit until its stdin is  closed.

To fix, use [ydl.StdoutPipe](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec#Cmd.StdoutPipe) to create the pipe between the two commands. The write side of this pipe is automatically closed when `ydl` exits, thus ensuring that `ffmpeg` reads to EOF and exits.

A second benefit of this fix is that the data is copied directly between the two child processes using an operating system pipe.  Using the io.Pipe solution in the question, the data flows from `ydl` to the parent process and back out to `ffmpeg`.

```
ydl := exec.Command("youtube-dl", data, "-o-")
ffmpeg := exec.Command("ffmpeg", "-i", "/dev/stdin", "-vn", "-f", "mp3", "-")

ydl.Stderr = os.Stderr
ydlOut, err := ydl.StdoutPipe()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

ffmpeg.Stdin = ydlOut
ffmpeg.Stdout = c.Writer
ffmpeg.Stderr = os.Stderr
fmt.Println("Starting-----------------------")
go func() {
    if err := ydl.Run(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}()

if err := ffmpeg.Run(); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Println("Done-----------------------")
```

https://go.dev/play/p/_Kr7hzgUKYK